# Favorite button programmatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm new to Swift.
I would like to know if possible add a "favorite" Button programmatically inside a view controller that inherits from UITableView?
I need to say too that I wanna use this button to favorite a result from google API.
This is possible once the result comes from a search's result and not from a specific list?
PS: I'm doing my project in **UIKIT**.
Thank you.

Comment: If you are using `UITableViewController` you will probably find it easier to use a `UIViewController` and add you tableview and other views to that

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course your view controller will then inherit from `UITableViewController`, not `UITableView`.

Here are the basics:

```
    var favoriteButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?
    var isFavorite: Bool = <...initial value...>
    var favoriteImage
    {
        return UIImage(systemName: "heart" + (isFavorite ? ".fill" : ""))
    }
```

```
    favoriteButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: favoriteImage,
                                         style: .plain,
                                         target: self,
                                         action: #selector(toggleFavorite))

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = favoriteButtonItem
```

```
    @objc private func toggleFavorite()
    {
        isFavorite = !isFavorite
        favoriteButtonItem.image = favoriteImage

        <...logic to process change...>
    }
```

You'll need to add logic to disable or not show yet `favoriteButtonItem` until the backend has returned the current value.